# Using the Loop command for a school assignment

Tags: java

Im doing an assignment for schools, and im just completely lost on how I should go about using a loop. Heres the code:

```
import java.util.Scanner; 

public class DrawHalfArrow {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scnr = new Scanner(System.in);
        int arrowBaseHeight = 0;
        int arrowBaseWidth  = 0;
        int arrowHeadWidth = 0;

        System.out.println("Enter arrow base height: " + arrowBaseHeight);
        arrowBaseHeight = scnr.nextInt();

        System.out.println("Enter arrow base width: " + arrowBaseWidth);
        arrowBaseWidth = scnr.nextInt();

        System.out.println("Enter arrow head width: " + arrowHeadWidth);
        arrowHeadWidth = scnr.nextInt();

        // Draw arrow base (height = 3, width = 2)
        System.out.println("**");
        System.out.println("**");
        System.out.println("**");

        // Draw arrow head (width = 4)
        System.out.println("****");
        System.out.println("***");
        System.out.println("**");
        System.out.println("*");

        return;
    }
}
```

I was wondering if anyone can help me? I dont even know where to begin....

Basically we have to make to so that the user input for the base, height and width of the arrow changes depending on what the user enters. Any help on what to do with this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: One thing that always helps: Reading tutorials

Comment: I really don't know what you're asking here.  Why do you even think you want a loop?

Comment: You need loops to print the correct number of `*` chars.

Comment: As @AndreasBrunnet has said already, reading up on `for` loops should get you a long way. Show us an attempt. If it fails, we’re here to help on why.

Comment: Other hints: Indent your code nicely. Once you get a loop in there, it will be unreadable unless you do. Your IDE can do it for you. And omit the final `return` statement, it’s superfluous so usually not written explicitly.

Comment: I did read tutorials and try to figure it out. Java isnt my strong suit (Coding in general isnt) and im just trying to get through this. I do college online and my instructor isnt always the most active in responding to emails.

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.util.Scanner; 

public class DrawHalfArrow{
public static void main(String[] args) {
Scanner scnr = new Scanner(System.in);
int arrowBaseHeight = 0;
int arrowBaseWidth  = 0;
int arrowHeadWidth = 0;

System.out.println("Enter arrow base height: " + arrowBaseHeight);
arrowBaseHeight = scnr.nextInt();

System.out.println("Enter arrow base width: " + arrowBaseWidth);
arrowBaseWidth = scnr.nextInt();

System.out.println("Enter arrow head width: " + arrowHeadWidth);
arrowHeadWidth = scnr.nextInt();

// Draw arrow base (height = 3, width = 2)
for (int i = 0; i < arrowBaseHeight; i++) {
for (int j = 0; j < arrowBaseWidth; j++) {
System.out.print("*");
}
System.out.println();
}

// Draw arrow head (width = 4)

for (int i = 0; i < arrowHeadWidth; i++) {
for (int j = arrowHeadWidth; j>i; j--) {
    System.out.print("*");
}
System.out.println();
}

}

}
```

Comment: Thank you for helping, instead of just telling me that tutorial help :)